# Junction table in yii php

Tags: php, yii, junction-table

I would like to create a junction table `tbl_guid_cost_centre` that gets taken care of without me manually saving it to the database. I tried adding this to my relations:

```
'costCentre' => [
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'CostCentre',
            'guid_to',
            'foreignKey' => 'guid',
            'tbl_guid_cost_centre(guid_to, cost_center_id)',
            "order" => "id desc"],
```

so that my when saving the costCentre, a row is created for it in my `tbl_guid_cost_centre`. However I'm getting the error:

> Property "CHasOneRelation.0" is not defined.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your junction table with the keyword `through` in your relations:

```
public function relations() {
        'guidCostCentre' => [
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'GuidCostCentre',
            ['guid_to' => 'guid']
        ],
        'costCentre' => [
            self::HAS_ONE,
            'CostCentre',
            'cost_centre_id',
            'through' => 'guidCostCentre'
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `HAS_ONE` relation in a wrong way. The first three elements of relation configuration array should be: relation type, related model name and foreign keys definition. All further elements should be indexed by keys related to relation properties. `'tbl_guid_cost_centre(guid_to, cost_center_id)',` probably generates this error, because it does not have a key, so it is treaded as a value for `0` property. You didn't share any details, so it is hard to guess what you want to achieve, but you should start from something like this:

```
'costCentre' => [
    self::HAS_ONE,
    'CostCentre',
    'guid_to',
    'order' => 'id desc',
],
```

And add additional settings at the end array with correct key.

Some examples and explanation you can find in the documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

Comment: can someone explain why was it downvoted **¯\\(°_o)/¯**

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The question was implementing junction table not the HAS_ONE relation.

Comment: @NickyMirfallah If you don't want to "has one relation", then why you're using `self::HAS_ONE` in your relation definition?

Comment: @rob006 you can take a look at my answer. Again, the question was for implementing the junction table ON a HAS_ONE relation.